# Insufficient Privileges error on old report as System Admin... can't even tell report type?

Tags: reporting, insufficient-privileges

I'm not sure how to tell the report type or what objects are being reported on since I can't open/edit the report. It's 4 years old sitting in a custom made folder, created by an admin years ago.

Report title: **QTD Forecast Report**

We have forecasting enabled in our org, although I don't think we actually use it currently. I'm not sure if I need some specific permission to access forecasting objects?

Any recommendations on how I can get more info on this report to figure out what permissions I need? I have the report ID from the URL, but it doesn't look like the SOAP API gives you much info about the report data itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely, this report was built with Forecasts 1.0, which was [officially retired in Summer '14](http://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter14/release-notes/rn_186_sales_forecasts1_eol_announce.htm). You could try to download the metadata into Eclipse/Mavensmate/Metadata Toolkit/Workbench/whatever-you-use-to-access-your-metadata, which might lead you to discover what the filters and so on originally were. There are now [two different types of forecasting](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=faq_forecasts3_whats_difference_between_versions.htm&language=en_US) you can use; however, they have to be enabled before you can use them. You're going to have to build your new reports from the ground up, though, because there's no way to change a report's type.